# Problema con los Observables

Tags: ionic, typescript, servicio, observable

tengo un problema, al presentar los datos en la vista con ionic 2.

** Este es la funcion de mi servicio **

```
 getUsers():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').map((datos) => datos.json());
  }
```

**Esta es la de mi vista, inicio.ts**

```
 respuesta = [];
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.apiServiceProvider.getUsers().subscribe((res) =>{
        this.respuesta.push(res);
        console.log(res);
      });
```

**Este es de mi vista inicio.html**

```
   <ion-card *ngIf="!respuesta">
     <ul id="todo-list">
          <li *ngFor="let item of respuesta" >
            {{ item.body }}
          </li>
      </ul>
    </ion-card>
```

En si, si imprimo los datos por consola.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo que falta? que esta saliendo mal?
Gracias.

Comment: Intenta removiendo el *ngIf="!respuesta" , yo también he llenado listas usando observables y solamente uso el *ngFor.

Comment: Ya lo intente, pero creo que el problema es que estoy resiviendo un array de Objetos, y los estoy guardando en otro array, como podria procesar esos valores? en que tipo de variable? en un array " [] " u objeto " {} "? ya que recibo un array []. @crrlos

Comment: en lugar de this.respuesta.push(res) prueba esto this.respuesta = res;

Un código de ejemplo:

https://bitbucket.org/snippets/crrlos/Kex8KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si haces `push` estas cargando al indice `respuesta[0]` el resultado de tu JSON... hay dos opciones:

Como lo tienes

```
 <ion-card *ngIf="!respuesta">
 <ul id="todo-list">
      <li *ngFor="let item of respuesta[0]" >
        {{ item.body }}
      </li>
  </ul>
</ion-card>
```

Como deberia ser:

```
this.respuesta = res;
```

Y en el html

```
<ion-card *ngIf="!respuesta">
 <ul id="todo-list">
      <li *ngFor="let item of respuesta" >
        {{ item.body }}
      </li>
  </ul>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: probare con ambas, gracias

Comment: como te fue? @JuanL

Comment: si funciono, como lo indicastes, gracias por estar pendiente.

Comment: @JuanL me alegro bro, si te sirvio puedes marcarla como correcta :D